# Terminal And Python console isn't showing Bangla

Tags: command-line, python, printing, gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I can't print anything in Bengali in Python console and Ubuntu terminal! When I try to print some Bengali characters in console or try to write Bengali in the terminal I just see some broken words! You can see it in my screenshot:

[image]

The same code is being used to show Bengali characters in CMD  window of Windows 7, so I am sure that this is not a programming problem, rather Ubuntu is not showing Bengali in my PC correctly. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: What is the word you used for test, could you write it in the post? btw Have you install Bengali language support?

Comment: @Sneetsher I wrote `হ্যালো ওয়ার্ল্ড`. Well I see single letters are shown without any problem like this one... `হ` or even words which are built upon single letters such as `বই`. But the problem is arising when I write joint letters like `ল্ড` which is consist upon two separate letters `ল` and `ড`. I can write Bengali sentences in `Gedit` and `Libre` office writer without any problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most terminals including `gnome-terminal` do not support Unicode shaping.

- Try with `konsole` (KDE) or `mlterm`, each had implemented a shaping functionality.

[image: Konsole - Unicode shaping support]

Comment: IDLE is not showing it right..the chars are garbled..

Comment: @heemayl , yep you are right (I dropped it). I copied directly from browser thinking that it's  *normalized* (but it wasn't,  not same support of Arabic). However, I couldn't get `ল` and `ড` to combine in LibreOffice. Could you provide me with another easy combination to try.

Comment: @Sneetsher sorry for late reply. It was night in my country and I had to go to bed for some sleep. However Many thanks. Well so it is not the problem of Python or Terminal. Now I am over sure. Can you please tell me how can I install Konsole on my Ubuntu? I tried using `sudo apt-get install konsole` but it says I need to fetch 66MB! Just want to know if I was doing the write thing.

Comment: @MikeFriedman , Yep that's correct because it is a part from KDE. It does depend  on KDE & Qt core libraries.

Comment: ummm..actually I use avro phonetic (I don't know you if you have used it or not)..but I will have a look when I get back home :)

Comment: @Sneetsher `ন্ড = ন+ড` `দ্ধ = দ+দ+ধ` `স্ম = স+ম` `ল্প = ল+প`  I can write `ল্ড` on Libre. You need to write using `shift`...  `ল্ড = ল+shift+ড` :)